# Absolute value from nested list using recursion

Tags: python, recursion, nested-lists

I have this nested list:

```
list1 = [2,-6, [8,-12,-12, [4, [-6], -3]], 7, [3.55, -3.55]].
```

And I have to use recursion to get absolute values of all elements from the lists so output stays as a list:

```
[2, 6, [8, 12, 12, [4, [6], 3]], 7, [3.55, 3.55]].
```

This is the code:

```
def rec_abs(a):
    new_list=[]
    for el in a:
        if isinstance(el, list):
            new_list.append(rek_abs(el))
        else:
            new_list.append(el)

    return new_list

print(rek_abs([2,-6, [8,-12,-12, [4, [-6], -3]], 7, [3.55, -3.55]]))
```

Can You give me some tips to solve it (I dont expect full solultion, just some tips)?

Thank You a lot!

Comment: you've typo in your code. `rec_abs` and `rek_abs`. then use `abs(el)` to append.

Comment: Do you want to modify the same list? Or return a completely different one?

Comment: @GOLDSPEED It doesn't matter, if I modify the list or make a new one. Just the output format has to be the same as the input

Comment: @MartinSuits Okay, see my answer for a viable alternative. The accepted answer is fine, but this is just for reference.

Comment: @GOLDSPEED Thanks, I keep that in mind. I had a task, where I had to use recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is perfect, just use `abs()` to convert it into absolute value

Note : You have typo in code as rec_abs and rek_abs, which I modified it in below code

```
def rec_abs(a):
    new_list=[]
    for el in a:
        if isinstance(el, list):
            new_list.append(rec_abs(el))
        else:
            new_list.append(abs(el))
    return new_list

print(rec_abs([2,-6, [8,-12,-12, [4, [-6], -3]], 7, [3.55, -3.55]]))

[2, 6, [8, 12, 12, [4, [6], 3]], 7, [3.55, 3.55]]
```

Comment: Thank You, akash karothiya! I also tried with abs function, but I put the abs to the wrong place :)

Answer (score 1):

For reference, modifying the list in-place is a simple, more efficient alternative, so you should consider this whenever possible. When iterating, iterate over the indices, and assign the return value to the ith index.

```
def rec_abs(a):
    for i, el in enumerate(a):
        a[i] = rec_abs(el) if isinstance(el, list) else abs(a[i])

    return a
```

```
lst = [2,-6, [8,-12,-12, [4, [-6], -3]], 7, [3.55, -3.55]]

print(rec_abs(lst))
[2, 6, [8, 12, 12, [4, [6], 3]], 7, [3.55, 3.55]]
```